# How can I make requests.get make the filename index.html if it's downloading a webpage

Tags: python

I'm trying to rewrite the Unix command wget in python for a project I'm making for fun, and I need it to save a webpage as index.html and normal files with their normal file name. But everything I tried doesn't seem to work. Here is the code sample:

```
import os
import requests
user_input = "wget google.com"
parts = user_input.split()
if parts[0] == "wget":
    # Check if the user just typed in wget
    if user_input == "wget":
        print(
            "wget: missing URL\nUsage: wget [URL]..."
            )
    # If not, run wget
    else:
        try:
            # Store the url the user put in in a variable
            url = parts[1]
            # Get the file name from the url
            file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
            # Destination
            destination = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file_name)
            # Checking if the user typed in a url with http or https. If they didn't, it will add http:// to the url.
            if not url.startswith("https://") and not url.startswith("http://"):
                url = "http://" + url
            # Send an HTTP GET request to the URL
            response = requests.get(url)
            # If the response status code is not 200, raise an exception
            response.raise_for_status()

            # Write the response content to the destination file
            with open(destination, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
            print("'{}' saved".format(file_name))

        # Catching any exception
        except Exception as e:
            print("wget: An error occurred:", e)
            print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
            print("Response content:", response.content)
```

Comment: what did u mean here:  file_name = url.split("/")[-1] or "index.html" is that ok ? would save google.com here which is obvious.

Comment: @Amin Samani yeah, that's the solution AI gave me.

Comment: @Amin Samani yeah, it is saving the google page but when the user inputs something that is a webpage like google.com I need it to save it like 'index.html' to not have to rename the file.

Comment: @AminSamani i could do that but if the user typed in something that is not a webpage, it'd still save it as 'index.html'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this if statement after the response variable getting a value and placing the destination variable after this if statement worked pretty well. (sorry if i said it wrong.):

```
if "text/html" in response.headers["content-type"]:
    filename = "index.html"
```